# How to expand view width to available free space in react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ios

Hi I am trying to design a screen in react native. If you see below screenshot here three views are there. a) image b) center view where text is appeared c) circle view

I want to expand center view width such it covers complete available space. I tried to do using flex property but couldn't make it. Does anyone know how to do it ?

[image]

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
    <Icon name="user" size={30} />
    <Text
      style={{
        textAlignVertical: "center",
        marginLeft: 20
      }}
    >
      Ajay Saini
    </Text>
  </View>
  <Text style={{ marginLeft: 50 }}>Hello</Text>
</View>


<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", width: "100%" }}>
  <Icon name="user" size={30} />
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: "column",
      marginLeft: 20
    }}
  >
    <Text>Williams</Text>
    <Text>
      {item.text}jhfjks ahfdkjsdh fjkshfjksaddhfjksdahfjkds
      ahajkdhfjksahdf
    </Text>
  </View>
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "flex-end"
    }}
  >
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderRadius: 100
      }}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Remove flex: 1 from circular view. Make only center view flex: 1, otherwise, these two will split the space equally.

Comment: @Eden correct. Thanks can you answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since your circular view has `flex: 1`, it tries to occupy all the free space. Also, center view tries to do the same. Which results in splitting the free space evenly, therefore **removing** `flex: 1` style from circular view will be enough.

Additionally, you can try adding a `justifyContent: 'space-between'` to most outer view. This is a great option to simplify more complicated designs.

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <Icon name="user" size={30} />
  <View
    style={{
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: "column",
      marginLeft: 20
    }}
  >
    <Text>Williams</Text>
    <Text>
      {item.text}jhfjks ahfdkjsdh fjkshfjksaddhfjksdahfjkds
      ahajkdhfjksahdf
    </Text>
  </View>
  <View
    style={{
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "flex-end"
    }}
  >
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderRadius: 100
      }}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this part to `flex: 2`.

```
<View
  style={{
    // flex: 1,
    flex: 2
    flexDirection: "column",
    marginLeft: 20
  }}
>
  <Text>Williams</Text>
  <Text>
    {item.text}jhfjks ahfdkjsdh fjkshfjksaddhfjksdahfjkds 
    ahajkdhfjksahdf
  </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not quite true. Changing flex 1 to 2 will only make center view share the free space twice the circular view does. The correct one is letting center view to be the *only* `flex: 1` style holder